# Strange stuff with custom class and @property int's

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created a class called "card" with the following header file and a body file with the @synthesize's. The problem is that the app crashes when i try to get the value of typeOfCard. Am i stupid? When i debug it, the inspctor tells me that this variable is an int and it tells me the correct value, but then the app crashes with the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM idOfImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x190f64e0'

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

enum cardType {
    hearth = 0,
    bell = 1,
    acorn = 2,
    leaf = 3
    };

@interface card : NSObject {
    int value;
    int idOfImage;
    enum cardType typeOfCard;
}

@property (assign)int value;
@property (assign)int idOfImage;
@property enum cardType typeOfCard;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the following:

1) declare your enum like (tip: use capital letters for enumerators, same as with classes)

```
typedef enum {
    hearth = 0,
    bell = 1,
    acorn = 2,
    leaf = 3
} CardType;
```

2) correct your @property line

```
@property (assign) CardType typeOfCard;
```

3) make sure you have the `@synthesize typeOfCard;` in your .m

Comment: Hi thank's for all that. I already solved the problem. It was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

The error message was correct. I failed a little bit and i tried to do NSARRAY.idOfCard instead of my card class.